# Ploting RGB or Hex values on a Color wheel using JS/Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, plot, rgb

I have an array of processed RGB values that I would like to plot onto a colour wheel like the one below.

eg.

```
RGBList = [
    {'r':231,'g':52,'b':35},
    {'r':24,'g':111,'b':24}
];
```

I would like each object in the example list above to be plotted as a marker/dot on top of the circle.

I've found code to create a colour wheel in a canvas in numerous fashions, but can't for the life of me figure out or find information on converting an RGB code into a reasonable XY coordinate for the purpose of plotting.

Colour Wheel Canvas code example: http://jsfiddle.net/yH6JE/

If any one can help I'd prefer if the answer be raw JS and HTML using a canvas. It's for a hobby project I'm doing and I want to plot average RGB values and also Kmeans centroids for representation of kmeans clustering (Machine Learning) just to give my results a visual representation rather than straight data.

[image: Colour Wheel]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See a forked fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/havdto6e/4/

What I did was 2 things:

1. Add a fade-to-white gradient to the colors circle so the value is represented
2. Add a function to plot an RGB color on to the wheel.
   For this the RGB coordinates were converted to HSV coordinates using the function from [here](http://axonflux.com/handy-rgb-to-hsl-and-rgb-to-hsv-color-model-c)

Note that some RGB values will be plotted at the same location as the value ("brightness") is not represented. In color pickers, the value is usually selected in a separate slider.
For example, these two different colors will appear in the same place on the circle:

```
{'r':255,'g':128,'b':128},
{'r':153,'g':77,'b':77}
```

Comment: Ahhh thank you! I did indeed find both these individual things myself also, but didn't spend long enough trying to understand the maths to combine the two. This essentially does what I'm looking for! Many thanks!